# Hook Installed False

Tags: git, redmine, gitolite, redmine-plugins

What is the **repository hook?**

Hooks false. How does "hook installed" work?

I'm using Redmine 2.3.1 Redmine Git Hosting Plugin 0.6 Centos 6 Git 1.7.1

Comment: The question is very obscure. I guess you mean Git hook scripts. These are scripts, which should run, when, e.g., a user commits to the repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look, as an example, to the section "[HowTo setup automatic refresh of repositories in Redmine on commit (Git)](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_setup_automatic_refresh_of_repositories_in_Redmine_on_commit#Git)", you will see:

> Simply add a `post-receive` (even on a Windows system, no extension is required) script file in the `hooks sub-directory` which contains the HTTP request call:

```
#!/bin/sh

curl "http://<redmine url>/sys/fetch_changesets?key=<your service key>"
```

> Don't forget to make the file(s) executable on UNIXish systems, more information about Git hooks can be found in the [githooks man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks).

So "repository hooks" probably references your `hooks` subdirectory within your `.git` folder of your local repo.

```
$GIT_DIR/hooks/*
```